# Reading the excel file(.xlsx) not supported using AJAX JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

Actualy i want to load the content of excel file when clicked on button.When i change the extension to .csv it works fine but when i change the file extension to .xlsx then it shows me the character type error like "y���!+��E���fMy�k�����K�5=|�t ��G)�s墙�U��tB��)���" .i get these types of similar character inside table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.12.12/cpexcel.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.12.12/xlsx.min.map"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <h1 align="center">CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</h1>
    <br />
    <div align="center">
     <button type="button" name="load_data" id="load_data" class="btn btn-info">Load Data</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="employee_table">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load_data').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url:"book.xlsx",
   dataType:"text",
   success:function(data)
   {
    var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table_data = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
    for(var count = 0; count<employee_data.length; count++)
    {
     var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
     table_data += '<tr>';
     for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++)
     {
      if(count === 0)
      {
       table_data += '<th>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
      }
      else
      {
       table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
      }
     }
     table_data += '</tr>';
    }
    table_data += '</table>';
    $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
   }
  });
 });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example header says it’s reading CSV. The example code also expects comma-separated text. It’s obviously not going to read other file formats including xslx.

So, it really depends on how you changed the file extension. If you simply renamed the file, the code will continue to work. But if you went into excel and said “Save As ..” the file format is going to be unrecognizable to your code.

Comment: how can i change the header so that it can read the xslx file??

Comment: I was referring to `<h1 align="center">CSV File to HTML Table Using AJAX jQuery</h1>`. Can you open the file in vi or notepad and confirm it's still a CSV? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values